# Cannot resolve method 'childMethod' in 'Sup3r'

Tags: java, inheritance

Consider the following two classes:

```
public class Sup3r {
    public void sup3rMethod() {}
}

public class Child extends Sup3r {
    public void childMethod() {}
}
```

and the following three statements:

```
s.sup3rMethod();
c.childMethod();
s.childMethod();
```

The last statement gives

> Cannot resolve method 'childMethod' in 'Sup3r'

Why?

Comment: Probably because `s` is a `Sup3r` and not a `Child`. Since we can't see where you defined `s` or `c` we can but speculate.

Comment: Please show the full example code, including the creation of `s` and `c`.

Comment: Because ... polymorphism.  In the `s.childMethod( )` call, the compiler only knows that `s` is a `Sup3r`.  The `Sup3r` does not define the `childMethod`.  Consider the possibility that there is some other child class of `Sup3r`.  It won't define (that) `childMethod`.  The Compiler is not allowed to assume that `Child` is the only subclass in existence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because the method `childMethod` only exists in the subclass `Child`. `Sup3r` is not inheriting this method from `Child` therefore the `childMethod` cannot be called using `s`.

If the reference variable `s` contains a `Child` instance then you can make it work by `casting` `s` to a
`Child` type first and then calling the method on s.

```
((Child)s).childMethod();
```

If the reference variable `s` does not in fact contain a `Child` instance then you will get a `ClassCastException` instead.

EDIT:

There is one other way you could make it work and that is by making the superclass `Sup3r` `abstract` and adding the abstract method `childMethod()`
to the class like so:

```
public abstract class Sup3r {
    public void sup3rMethod() {}
    public abstract void childMethod();
}

public class Child extends Sup3r {
    public void childMethod() {} //implementation code here, the empty block would suffice too however.
}
```

`abstract` means that you leave the implementation of the method `childMethod()` to one of `Sup3r`s implementing subclasses. If you make this change to your code then you should be able to call `childMethod()` on `s` without having to cast to `Child` first. But the result of `childMethod()` will depend on the specific `childMethod()` method implementation of the subclass instance that `s` references.

Comment: The 'abstract' is what will solve my problem. I've had a complete mental block on this! :( Thanks for your help.